# Using For Loop Append. Add characters from string in order to elements before append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I append my elements using the for loop.

```
for ( i = 0; i < 28; i++ ) {
  var $sound = '<nav class="cell"><a class="pointer blacktxt" data-asound="'+ i +'"><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></a></nav>'
  var $csound = '<nav class="cell"><input type="text" class="txtcenter" data-csound="'+ i +'" placeholder="'+ i +'" /></nav>'
  var $newDiv = $('<header class="table lessonSec" data-alphabet="'+ i +'"/>').html($sound + $csound)
  $(".lesson").append( $newDiv )
}
```

Because I use the for loop to append my elements from 0-28; I would like to add the letters from the string in order as a new data-attribute in the for loop.

**NOTE:** The Arabic alphabet has 28 letters and it's a cursive language written from right to left.

```
var char = "ابتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوي";
```

Here's an example of how I want the elements to be dynamically appended.

I've been working on this for hours and I have no idea how to proceed with doing something like this.

Does anyone know how to do this and can walk me through it?

```js
$("body").append('<div class="lesson blacktxt"></div>')

var char = "ابتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوي";

for ( i = 0; i < 28; i++ ) {
  var $sound = '<a class="pointer" data-asound="'+ i +'"><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></a>'
  var $csound = '<input type="text" class="wauto" data-csound="'+ i +'" placeholder="'+ i +'" />'
  var $newDiv = $('<p class="lessonSec" data-alphabet="'+ i +'"/>').html($sound + $csound)
  $(".lesson").append( $newDiv )
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #7fb8ff;
}

/* Global Misc Classes */
.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20%;
}

.wauto {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/poly/css/application.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you have hardcoded string, reverse it and cut your task in half

Comment: so use `prepend`? Loop backwards? Maybe I have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: Prepend is not going to work in this case. I want to add characters from a string `char = "abcdefg"` into newly appended elements in order. I gave a few examples in my post to better understand the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a variable `len` set to `char.length - 1`, decrement `len` within `for` loop, set `data-alphabet` to `char[len]`

```js
$("body").append('<div class="grid"><div class="grid__col--12 lesson blacktxt"></div></div>');

var char = "ابتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوي";

for (i = 0, len = char.length - 1; i < 28; i++, len--) {
  var $sound = '<nav class="cell"><a class="pointer blacktxt" data-asound="'+ i +'"><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></a></nav>'
  var $csound = '<nav class="cell"><input type="text" class="txtcenter" data-csound="'+ i +'" placeholder="'+ i +'" /></nav>'
  var $newDiv = $('<header class="table lessonSec" data-alphabet="'+ char[len] +'"/>').html($sound + $csound)
  $(".lesson").append( $newDiv )
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #7fb8ff;
}

/* Center DIVs Vertically and Horizontally */
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Global Misc Classes */
.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.txtcenter {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/poly/css/application.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I understand now thanks man. This is helps a lot. I didn't even think about using .length

Answer (score 0):

Consider this snippet:

```
var chars = "ابتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهوي";


var arrayOfChars = chars.split('').reverse(); // got them in reverse order

var divs = arrayOfChars.map(buildDiv)

$('.mydiv').prepend(divs)


function buildDiv(c) {
  return $('<div />').attr('data-around', c)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did notice you're try to add the data-attribue inside of 
`$(".lesson").append( $newDiv )`

You need to use `$('.selector').data('your_attribute', 'whatever you want to add');`

or

`$('.selector').attr('your_attribute', 'whatever you want to add');`

If you don't do this ^ you won't be able to add anything to the data attribute. Based off your question I'm not sure if this is the problem you're having but it will definitely effect your outcome.

Good luck!

Comment: well it really have nothing to do with ajax, also you don't have to use `$.data` to setup data attribute, using `$.attr` works just fine

Comment: You're right, I was doing something weird today with ajax, for some reason I associated this with that similar task. lol

And yes he could also use $.attr also although he's not using either.